# Convert Tracked Changes to Text in MS Word WITH Move Formatting

Tags: ms-word

I'm trying to convert tracked changes into formatted text.  I have the terrific macro below from @CindyMeister that works great, but it doesn't handle move changes (green double strikethrough for moved from and green double underline for moved to).  I added lines for moved to and moved from, but can't seem to figure out how to keep the green text color.  Does anyone know how I can update the macro to fix that?

```
Sub FormatRevisions()
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim rev As Word.Revision

    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    doc.TrackRevisions = False
    For Each rev In doc.Revisions
        Select Case rev.Type
            Case wdRevisionMovedFrom
                rev.Range.Font.DoubleStrikeThrough = True
                rev.Reject
            Case wdRevisionMovedTo
                rev.Range.Underline = wdUnderlineDouble
                rev.Accept
            Case wdRevisionDelete
                rev.Range.Font.StrikeThrough = True
                rev.Reject
            Case wdRevisionInsert
                rev.Range.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
                rev.Accept
            Case wdRevisionFormat
                 MsgBox "revision format"
                rev.Accept
            Case wdRevisionStyle
                 MsgBox "revision style"
                rev.Accept
            Case wdRevisionStyleDefinition
                 MsgBox "revision style def"
                rev.Accept
            Case wdRevisionSectionProperty
                 MsgBox "revision section prop"
                rev.Accept
            Case wdRevisionReplace
                 MsgBox "revision replace"
                rev.Accept
            Case wdRevisionTableProperty
                 MsgBox "revision table property"
                rev.Accept
            Case wdRevisionReconcile
                 MsgBox "revision reconcile"
                rev.Accept
            Case wdRevisionProperty
                 MsgBox "revision property"
                rev.Accept
            Case wdRevisionParagraphProperty
                 MsgBox "revision para property"
                rev.Accept
            Case wdRevisionParagraphNumber
                 MsgBox "revision para number"
                rev.Accept
            Case wdRevisionDisplayField
                 MsgBox "revision display field"
                rev.Accept
            Case wdRevisionConflict
                MsgBox "revision conflict"
                rev.Accept
            Case wdNoRevision
                MsgBox "no revision"
                rev.Accept
            Case Else
                MsgBox "unknown type"
                doc.Comments.Add rev.Range, "unknown type"
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: If you're a trial lawyer, you should be able to hire someone to make the changes for you. :-) Why would you feel your time is too precious and allows you to ask us to do it for you for free?

Comment: Ken, thanks for the lead. I'm sorry to have disturbed you. If you ever need 10 minutes of IP litigation advice with something you're having trouble doing on your own feel free to look me up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the green text color using the following code:

```
rev.Range.Font.TextColor = Rgb(44, 98, 52)
```